# Why remove_meta_box() function is not working in my plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to delete the section **WordPress News** in my dashboard by creating a simple plugin. First of all, i've made a php file in the following directory:

> wp-content/plugins/basic-plugin.php

In the basic-plugin.php file i have the following block of code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Basic Plugin
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/plugins/basic-plugin/
Description: My first plugin for creating and displaying job opportunities
Author: Rumen Panchev
Version: 1.0
License: GPLv2
*/

function ru_remove_dashboard_widget() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'post_container_1' );
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'ru_remove_dashboard_widget' );
```

The problem is that the section is still in the dashboard. Im new in WordPress Development and not sure why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct however you're using the wrong context argument with `remove_meta_box()`. Dashboard widgets aren't registered under `post_container_1`.

Valid options for the context argument include 'normal', 'advanced' or 'side'. For the particular dashboard widget you're attempting to remove, you need 'side'.

```
remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );
```

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks.